# How do I add listeners to these buttons?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

[image]

This is the mockup of a simple downloader I want to make. I can create the view as shown below however I do not know how the listeners for the pause and cancel button will work.

The problem is in knowing exactly which view's button was clicked. In other words, getting the index of the view.

How can I retrieve that ?

Comment: can you show us what you did to get the progressBar?

Comment: @CarlSaldanha Created a custom adapter by extending `BaseAdapter`

Comment: every view can have unique id assigned to it so you can figure which view was clicked as there will be different listeners for different buttons based on id

Comment: @Peshal I didn't get u. All the views will have the ids defined in the XML file which will be same for all the views. They are unique in the context of a particular view. 
I was wondering if `setTag()` can be put to use somehow.

Comment: no all the view elements will have different ids i.e. if you have two buttons you can assign two different ids for each button so that u know which button was clicked

Comment: @Peshal OK, understood. Now I have 100 downloads going on. How do I know which download's stop button was clicked, for example ? :)

Comment: Thats a good question, i didnt realize that, ok show us how u get 100 downloads at once and we can look at the code, its hard to say without looking at the code.

Comment: @Peshal User can enter a URL and press the download button. Say for example `www.videos.com/gangnam.mp4` . And he enters more videos . and more and so on. I haven't written code, yet. I am just doing a bit of requirements analysis. Jotting down problems I encounter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `getView` method of the `BaseAdapter` you set the `onClickLister` for each button and save the index of the row (position parameter) as the tag for each button. When a button is clicked you retrieve this tag to know which row the button resides in.